# Using SSL with ejabberd

Tags: ssl, ejabberd

I am using zeroSSL with letsencrypt to generate a SSL.

I have the next files generated by zeroSSL and I installed in my website without problem.

My problem is how install it in ejabberd running into windows.

I have the next files generated by zeroSSL wizard.

account-key.txt

domain-key.txt

domain-crt.txt

domain-csr.txt

Please How could I set the certfiles and port to use SSL in ejabberd with windows with these files?

Comment: not sure about the windows installation. But you need to edit the ssl certificate file paths in ejabberd.yml file.

Comment: For reference, this is also posted in https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3085